# Need a title - spaceship AI, 1980s

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

I read a paperback in the early-to-mid 1980s that I'm trying to find again.  It was pretty basic space opera, as I recall, but the spaceship AIs were characters as well.  Near the end, the bad guy has taken over the hero's ship & mindwipes it ... only all the other ships give her back her memories.  I'm sorry I can't offer more clues.  There were ships on both sides of the conflict & they all helped in the memory restoration, I think.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. Was this a case where the AIs were originally humans who had had their brains/memories transferred into the ships by any chance?

Comment: This sounds like Ian M. Banks Culture Series, the first was "Consider Phlebus" from 1987. They are ship based AI's, or Culture Minds.

Comment: The one you are thinking of may be the GSV "Lasting Damage". After it was destroyed in battle, a recorded copy of its mind-state was embodied in a new Mind and incorporated into another GSV of the same class. Its original Mind was later found to have survived the ship's destruction and was also incorporated into a new combat GSV.

Comment: Another possibility is "The Ship Who Dissembled" by Anne McCaffrey.

Comment: Published in 1969. The Brainships contain infants with severe birth defects who are placed in self-contained life-support shells in which they will spend their entire lives, and are trained to become the "brain" of a starship. Hijackers capture several Brainships (see Brain & Brawn Ships) and remove from each the life-support shell containing the "brain", leaving the shellperson inside unable to see, hear, or otherwise sense anything outside the shell. One goes mad before rescue arrives. In direct response to this incident, subsequent shells are designed with integrated audiovisual inputs.

Comment: The series is known as "The Ship who Sang Series" after the first book of the series.

Comment: [Cruiser Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruiser_Dreams)?